# No puedo importar base de datos wordpress

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

Realicé una exportación de una base de datos de Wordpress que tenía en cdmon con la base de datos llamada `7navasethsfdghsrtyu` y ahora me registré en Ionos y quiero importar esa página Wordpress. Lo primero que hice es crear la base de datos en Ionos llamada `dbs291211` y luego le doy a importar eligiendo la copia de seguridad de la base de datos `7navasethsfdghsrtyu.sql`. He leído que hay que modificar el `wp_config` para conectar con la base de datos nueva pero no hay ningún fichero llamado así. Al finalizar la importación me salta el error 1046. Adjunto capturas.

Un saludo y gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Estás realizando el volcado a través de PhpMyAdmin?

Comment: Sí, hice la exportación de wordpress desde phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu error es no haber seleccionado la base de datos hacia la que quieres realizar el volcado, te doy dos soluciones que deberían de funcionar:

- Desde PhpMyAdmin: vete a tu base de datos (búscala donde te muestra todas las bases de datos disponibles) si es que la tienes creada ya, la seleccionas y vas a donde dice `Import`, ahí seleccionas tu fichero y no deberías de tener ningún problema.
- Si lo haces desde el menú principal de PhpMyAdmin sin seleccionar ninguna base de datos previamente o a través de consola, estaría bien que añadieras un par de sentencias en tu script de volcado: una para crear la base de datos si no existe (esto te facilitará mover la BD a un servidor donde no tengas ni la base de datos creada, puede no ser necesario en tu caso) y una segunda para seleccionar la base de datos (el fallo te lo da por este motivo), tal que así:

`CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS TuBaseDeDatos;`

`USE TuBaseDeDatos;`

Deberás cambiar TuBaseDeDatos por el nombre de tu base de datos hacia la que quieras hacer el volcado, ya sea existente o recién creada por ti, si cambias el nombre deberás de volver a configurar tu wordpress para que apunte hacia esa nueva base de datos, si por el contrario mantienes el nombre original y lo que estás haciendo es migrar el sitio, no deberías de tener ningún contratiempo.

Comment: entiendo que sería añadir la nueva base de datos que cree en ionos no?

Comment: Abrí con el Sublime Text el bade de datos sql exportada y sería añadir estas sentencias en este trozo de código no?                                                                       --
-- Base de datos nueva en Ionos: `dbs291211`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `wp_booking`
--
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS TuBaseDeDatos;

USE TuBaseDeDatos;

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta, de todas formas, ¿la base de datos ya existe?

Comment: @AarónVeraCerdeña donde pone TuBaseDeDatos deberías de poner el nombre de la base de datos hacia la que quieres volcar los datos, por lo que puedo leer en tu captura es algo como `7navasethsfdghsrtyu`

Comment: La base de datos en ionos la cree nueva y se llama dbs291211. La antigua se llama 7navasethsfdghsrtyu

Comment: Perfecto, ese es el nombre que deberías en lugar de `TuBaseDeDatos`:

`CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS dbs291211;
USE dbs291211;`

Comment: Vale y eso debo meterlo directamente en el código o desde donde lo introduzco desde phpmyadmin o desde sublime text

Comment: Si lo haces a través del PhpMyAdmin no te haría falta introducir nada, simplemente fíjate en tener seleccionada la base de datos, vete a `import` y listo (como explico en la respuesta), este enlace te puede ser de utilidad: https://help.one.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005588189-How-do-I-import-a-database-to-phpMyAdmin-

Comment: solucionado!!! metí las sentencias en el código modificando el fichero .sql desde Sublime y perfecto. Muchas gracias crack

Answer (score 0):

Revisa que tengas los siguientes elementos en tu wp-config y que se correspondan con tu base de datos:

```
// ** wp-config.php ** //
define( 'DB_NAME', 'database_name_here' );
define( 'DB_USER', 'username_here' );
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'password_here' );
define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );
```

Comment: pero es que en la base de datos no tengo ningún fichero wp_config.php. Podría crearlo de nuevo?? He intentado cambiar el nombre de la base de datos desde phpmyadmin pero me dice que no tengo privilegios.

Comment: no en la base de datos, en el directorio donde tengas el wordpress en el servidor, seguramente accedas desde filezilla o algun gestor similar